# How to get Everyone except external users using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm actually using Power Automate to set the permissions but cannot find the id or ultimately the Uri for get command. Here's what I'm using but doesn't work:

```
_api/web/SiteGroups/GetByName('Everyone except external users')
```

Does anyone know how I'd use REST to get that specific domain group?

Comment: What are you going to do with this AD group? Add to an SP group? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To get "everyone except external users"**

- Get an ID of your [Azure AD tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/find-your-office-365-tenant-id?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fFind-your-Office-365-tenant-ID-6891b561-a52d-4ade-9f39-b492285e2c9b).
- Construct a group name in this format:

```
c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/<AZURE AD TENANT ID>
```

**Example of a group name**

```
c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/b9c6be6c-5dbf-4ce7-b21e-c21c8cbd77e5
```

**POST request to ensure the "everyone except external users"**

You might want to make sure that this AD group is "ensured" in your site. If it is not, then you won't be able to locate it via REST:

```
/_api/Web/ensureUser('c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/b9c6be6c-5dbf-4ce7-b21e-c21c8cbd77e5')
```

**Body of the POST request**

```
{}
```

**Sample response**

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://CONTOSO.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicTeam/_api/Web/GetUserById(11)",
      "uri": "https://CONTOSO.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicTeam/_api/Web/GetUserById(11)",
      "type": "SP.User"
    },
    "Alerts": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://CONTOSO.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicTeam/_api/Web/GetUserById(11)/Alerts"
      }
    },
    "Groups": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://CONTOSO.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicTeam/_api/Web/GetUserById(11)/Groups"
      }
    },
    "Id": 11,
    "IsHiddenInUI": false,
    "LoginName": "c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/b9c6be6c-5dbf-4ce7-b21e-c21c8cbd77e5",
    "Title": "Everyone except external users",
    "PrincipalType": 4,
    "Email": "",
    "Expiration": "",
    "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": false,
    "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": false,
    "IsSiteAdmin": false,
    "UserId": null,
    "UserPrincipalName": null
  }
}
```

**Get external users by Title**

If you are sure that Everyone except external users is already ensured in your site, than you can get this group using this REST query:

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Title eq 'Everyone except external users'
```

Comment: Yes the filter=Title eq worked. Thanks.